# spring boot jwt no redirection after login authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

Need help in correcting my code it is not redirecting to home after login authentication

```
security config.java

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Security_Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("http="+http);
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
//      http.csrf().disable()
//      // dont authenticate this particular request
//      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
//      antMatchers("/Login.html").permitAll().
//      // all other requests need to be authenticated
//      anyRequest().authenticated().and().
//      // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
//      // store user's state.
//      exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
//      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/Login.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
        .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/Login").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/Login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/Home", true).permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/Logout")).permitAll()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/Login").permitAll()
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
        .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/Login")
                .and()
        .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
//      // If a user try to access a resource without having enough permissions
//      http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Login.html");

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion JWT authentication is handled differently than traditional form based authentication whereas after authentication we should return the JWTTocken instead of redirecting to another page.